# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory')

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting an error in PostMan fetching data from my API:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory')
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpGet("basket/{identifier}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<NewBasketDTO.ItemDTO>> FetchBasketEntries(string identifier)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
               HttpMethod.Get,
               $"https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{identifier}")
            {
                Headers = { { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" }, }
            };

            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            using var httpResponseMessage =
                await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            var basketEntires = Enumerable.Empty<NewBasketDTO.ItemDTO>();

            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return basketEntires;

            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

            var basketDTO = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                    <DTO.NewBasketDTO.ItemDTO>(contentStream, options);

            basketDTO = new NewBasketDTO.ItemDTO
            {
                ProductId = basketDTO.ProductId,
                Quantity = basketDTO.Quantity
            };

            return basketEntires; // 200 OK
        }
```

Here is my model DTO:

```
public class NewBasketDTO
    {
        public class ItemDTO
        {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }

        [ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
        public class BasketDTO
        {
            public string Identifier { get; set; }
            public List<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

I'm trying to get this data here from my API:

```
[
  {
    "productId": 0,
    "quantity": 0
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to fetch data from my API with Http in my controller and I want that data to be added to my NewBasketDTO and returned in JSON format so that I can post it to another database later on but I can't even seem to get it correctly without it giving me this error of value cannot be null

Comment: I don't know which method you're calling which has an argument called "factory". Can you use your debugger to walk through your code and inspect what value is null?

Comment: Is the controller in the client or server?  Normal sequence 1) client sends request with POST 2) server receives request with GET 3) Server processes the request 4) Server sends response with POST 5) client receives response with GET.  You can have a controller at both the client and server.

Comment: @jdweng It's in the client :) I have a controller at both

Comment: @gunr2171 That's the thing, I don't have anything named factory which is very peculiar, it doesn't give me any error in VS just in PostMan at System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactoryExtensions.CreateClient(IHttpClientFactory factory)

Comment: @gunr2171 I found this at the top of my controller:  private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

Comment: @gunr2171 and I added this : 
        public OrdersController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

Comment: @gunr2171 but now it says this in PostMan: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'AnimimoMicroservices.NewOrderService.Controllers.OrdersController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.

Comment: When you get a  Status like a 400 or 500 it means the server found an error an you will not get any data along with the error.  What you should do is display the Error code instead of trying to deserialize the return data.  What really happened is either the Server got an error while processing the request or the request was not valid.  The server can send a error response (along with the Status Code indicating error) so you have more details on the type of error that occurred.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for that concise answer my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The cause in my case was that the service `httpClientFactory` (I had a different variable name) was not injected in the constructor (I was using constructor DI). In case anyone faces this type of error, kindly check that the IHttpClientFactory is actually injected.